# How to set number of threads in MultithreadedMapRunner in Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am using JobConf and in that I am using multi-threaded mapper like this:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.MultithreadedMapRunner;
conf.setMapRunnerClass(MultithreadedMapRunner.class);
```

Now how do I set the number of threads ?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the Javadoc for the class, but there's a [JIRA bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-2815) about the javadoc not correctly generting for this class. Anyway, the property you're looking for is:

`mapred.map.multithreadedrunner.threads`